# Including column name as argument in function that uses dot notation

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to include the column name as an acceptable argument for this function to make it more flexible.

```
def func(df, column):
    return df.column.str.split('', n = 5, expand=True)
```

As expected, `func(my_df, columnX)` is returning a `NameError: name 'columnX' is not defined`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Read about dot and bracket notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your column as if it where a dictionary field. Another recommendation is not to name an object as it class name (replace `DataFrame` by `df`). Finally you need to return the obtained object.

```py
def func(df, column):
    return df[column].str.split('', n = 5, expand=True)
```

Comment: Omitted the return just for simplification. Good suggestion with dictionary field.

Comment: If you're obtaining a `NameError` then it's possible that the `column` variable is not defined. At this point you have two options `column = 'COLUMN_NAME'` and the `func(df, column)` or simpler, `func(df, 'COLUMN_NAME')` where `'COLUMN_NAME'` is the name of your column.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to garciparedes:**

```
def func(df, column: str):
    return df[column].str.split('', n = 5, expand=True)

func(df, column='column')
```